# DjangoCMS cant find templates - TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/djangocms_blog/post/add/

Tags: django, django-cms

I installed djangoCMS and djangocms-blog and tried to create my first blog post, but it seems the engine can't render the template for whatever reason.

It seems it can't render `{{ field.field }}` ?

Additionally, when trying ot create a new blog post, I can't select any app.config. I did then just click on `save and continuing editing` what throws the below error.

[image]

**Error log:**

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19

cms/plugins/widgets/ckeditor.html
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
18                          {% else %}
19                              {{ field.field }}
20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.help_text %}
23                          <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
24                      {% endif %}
25                  </div>
26              {% endfor %}
27          </div>
28      {% endfor %}
29  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I added "djangocms_text_ckeditor" to INSTALLED_APPS and that helped.